# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. You cannot use more than one 'in' filter

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am trying to execute 2 collections using `whereIn` like below.

```
db.collection("ABC").whereEqualTo("orgType", "Test")
                    .whereIn("dist", selectedAreaNames)
                    .whereIn("price", selectedPriceRanges)
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                     .................
                     .................
```

Where its working perfectly when I execute a single `whereIn`(i.e selectedAreaNames or selectedPriceRanges at a time) but for both it's throwing `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. You cannot use more than one 'in' filter` exception.

If firestore is allowing one `whereIn` at a time for now then is there any alternative solution for the above problem? Just like any other queries or claues etc which will help me to execute both at  a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternative is to perform a single "in" query, then filter the remaining results in the client app.  Firestore won't do it for you - it's a hard limit that can't be worked around.

Comment: Hmm. I think then its better to excute two quries with their own data collections at a time.

Comment: That's entirely up to you to decide.